# WAMP server as subdomain on IIS machine

Tags: php, .net, apache, iis, wamp

My boss wants me to merge my dev server on to the same server as our live production application.

The problem with this is that the current application is .NET and development is WAMP.

On my local machine this worked fine because I could just tag a port to the URL like :8080 or :81.

But, I have tried to point our testing subdomain to an alternate port, but, I found out this isn't possible with DNS.

How can I successfully leave IIS as the main host (www.domain.com) and serve requests for the subdomain (dev.domain.com) from WAMP?

Answer (score 0):

Since both services are webserver operating on port 80, you simply can't without moving one or another to a different port.

The only "workaround" that comes to mind is to set up a subdomain on IIS with redirect to your WAMP dev server.